# Best alternative to deliver EF Entities to JSON

Tags: c#, sql, json, entity-framework, linq

I've been testing performance and code readability for a function that delivers list of EF Entity items to an Ajax call (JSON).

Here's the code with 4 alternatives (ItemList1, ItemList2, ItemList3, and ItemList4) to deliver a list of my UserNotification entity to JSON:

```
public ActionResult GetLatestNotificationItems(int nStart, int nFinish)
    {

        int nCurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

        var ItemList1 = (from un in db.UserNotifications
                         where un.UserId == nCurrentUserId
                         orderby un.DateCreated descending, un.Id ascending
                         select new { DateCreated = un.DateCreated, HasBeenSeen = un.HasBeenSeen, Id = un.Id, Message = un.Message, Title = un.Title, UserId = un.UserId, ActionURL = un.ActionURL })
                        .Skip(nStart)
                        .Take(nFinish - nStart + 1).ToList();

        var ItemList2 = db.UserNotifications.Where(U => U.UserId == nCurrentUserId)
            .OrderByDescending(U => U.DateCreated)
            .ThenBy(U => U.Id)
            .Skip(nStart)
            .Take(nFinish - nStart + 1)
            .Select(s => new { DateCreated = s.DateCreated, HasBeenSeen = s.HasBeenSeen, Id = s.Id, Message = s.Message, Title = s.Title, UserId = s.UserId, ActionURL = s.ActionURL }).ToList();

        *//queryGetLatestNotificationItemsReturnType is just a class with the return types.* 
        var ItemList3 = db.Database.SqlQuery<queryGetLatestNotificationItemsReturnType>("SELECT Id, DateCreated, HasBeenSeen, Message, Title, UserId, ActionURL from UserNotifications Where UserID = " +
            "{0} ORDER BY DateCreated DESC, Id ASC OFFSET {1} ROWS FETCH NEXT {2} ROWS ONLY", nCurrentUserId, nStart, (nFinish - nStart + 1))
            .ToList();

        //disable ProxyCreation for "ItemList4" option. (To strip entities into POCO objects without the extra unnecessary EF data)
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var ItemList4 = db.UserNotifications.SqlQuery(
            "SELECT Id, DateCreated, HasBeenSeen, Message, Title, UserId, ActionURL from UserNotifications Where UserID = " +
            "{0} ORDER BY DateCreated DESC, Id ASC OFFSET {1} ROWS FETCH NEXT {2} ROWS ONLY", nCurrentUserId, nStart, (nFinish - nStart + 1))
            .ToList();

        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

        return Json(ItemList4, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

These where their times when executed (3 passes each):

- ItemList1: 28ms, 21ms, 16ms
- ItemList2: 22ms, 19ms, 18ms
- ItemList3: 15ms, 4ms, 5ms
- ItemList4: 18ms, 5ms, 7ms

NOW, the question is, which one is the **recommended** one to use?
Because:

- ItemList3 is the quickest to execute, but it requires a POCO
  structure creation apart from the EF model, and is RAW SQL instead of
  LINQ.
- ItemList4 is almost as quick, but it requires playing around with the context's ProxyCreationEnabled and is also RAW SQL instead of LINQ.
- And both ItemList1 and ItemList2 perform poorly but they use nice compilable, easier to read LINQ.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Is the poorer performance of compiling LINQ into SQL causing user experience issues? If not, don't bother with making it faster.

Answer (score -1):

You sound like you're looking at all the options... would you consider [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb)?

In terms of your criteria, for performance, the db access is vanilla ADO. There isn't a faster way. Also, you don't need to create your POCOs, they're generated for you at design time by QueryFirst, based on the schema returned by your query.

You say you like compiled linq instead of "raw sql". Are your reacting to SQL in string literals? You should! It's a mystery that this weird cultural practice continues. QueryFirst lets you put your sql *in its own file*. It's not compiled to IL, but it's validated by the editor as you type (with intellisense), test run by QueryFirst when you save the file, and generally elevated to the status of a language. Then just pass the `List<QueryResults>` (returned by the generated `Execute()` method) to your serializer and your outta there. Bear in mind that since the DB speaks SQL, any other option will be generating SQL behind the scenes. Why not take back control?